# Element not visible exception - even if different Selenium waits are used

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, wait

I am trying to automate functional testing of a web application using Selenium and Java. In my application there are several menus. When clicked on a particular menu, a drop down of sub menus appear
[click to view screenshot of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEnEx.jpg)

I use below code to click sub menu

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("id=menu")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("id=sub_menu_a")).click();
```

but the issue is that it throws a 'ElementNotVisibleException' at the second line. The same happens even if I use implicit wait

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

explicit wait

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("id=sub_menu_a")));
```

and fluent wait.

```
Wait<WebDriver> fluentWait=new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class,ElementNotVisibleException.class);
        WebElement element=fluentWait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver){
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("id=menu"));
                return driver.findElement(By.xpath("id=sub_menu_a"));
            }
        });
        element.click();
```

but no luck. But the code works fine if add sleep time using

```
Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
```

before and after the first line of code. But it is not a permanent solution since the page load time may vary depend on the network speed and the data in the page. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I think the webdriver can find the 'menu' and it clicks on it during the page is being load. Hence the menu is not popping down causing 'ElementNotVisibleException' on trying to find the submenu. So applied the all types of waits before clicking on the menu, still was a fail. Is there any way to wait until the page is completely loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    WebElement menu=driver.findElement(By.xpath("id=menu"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", menu);
    WebElement subMenu=driver.findElement(By.xpath("id=sub_menu_a"));
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", subMenu);
```

Hope this work

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Actions class and see if it works or not ...

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("id=menu")).click(); 
WebElement subMenu=driver.findElement(By.xpath("id=sub_menu_a"));   
Actions myaction = new Actions(driver);
myaction.moveToElement(subMenu);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(subMenu));
myaction.click().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fluent waits should work fine.
Try using something like this:

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("id=sub_menu_a")));
```

but I would go for css Selectors they are perfect for html pages.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#sub_menu_a")));
```

Or if your *sub_menu_a* is a child of *menu* I would go for

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#menu #sub_menu_a")));
```

Comment: I've edited my answer and added my FluentWait.
Your locators should be fine, since they works with sleep. Maybe ignoring ElementNotVisibleException is a problem.

Comment: The above solution works fine for 80% of time, but it fails once in a while

Comment: I often thought, that I had to use sleep. But it was always an Javascript wait problem. Are you using any UI Frameworks ?
For example with JQuery Mobile you have to wait for the css selector `html.ui-mobile-rendering` to be gone, otherwise the framework has not finished rendering.

And are you sure that your IDs are unique in the whole DOM tree, not just the visible page ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("id=sub_menu_a")));
```

Also it would be better if you can give html to find the right xpath as I think better XPATH will yield the result of click on the submenu.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I have the similar issue (don't remember the exact case so indeed your HTML page snipped would be helpful) so I was forced to use Thread.sleep()
To avoid long waits will propose something like this method:

```
static void waitAndClick(WebDriver driver, By by, int attempts, int sleep) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++) {
        WebElement element = null;
        try {
            element = driver.findElement(by);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
        if (element == null) {
            int time = sleep * (i + 1);
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } else {
            element.click();
            break;
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Error");
}
```

It's not a 100% complete solution but just an idea.

Comment: This works, but the problem is that I have added implicit waiting time of 30 seconds. So if the element is not found in first iteration, then webdriver will wait for 30 seconds to throw the exception.

Comment: You should either use implicit waiting or this aproach.